# How to mirror Dedicated Server

Tags: linux, centos, upgrade

I bought a dedicated server with cent os from 1&1.
I want to upgrade the cent os version on dedicated server.

Before that, i want to take a mirror of the server for backup. It hosts many websites.
Please let me know how i can do that. I have parallels plesk installed on the server.

I only have ssh access to server and it is on 1&1 infrastructure

Answer (score 1):

First we need to u mount the partition where our plesk is installed, Later on we will remove the entry of same partition from FSTAB file.

The data of partition wouldn't be affect in case of unmounted partition, Thus we can easily upgrade the our Centos Operating System Using below command.

The command to use to upgrade the O.s is "yum update"

Comment: I only have ssh access to server and it is on 1&1 infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

Except above, You can install another updated kernel in your system & check whher it supports to your hardware or not.

If it supports to your hardware then you can easily go through with updated partition other wise your data would be safe in previous one.